# Automating spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have some industrial data that i wish to present in a spotfire dashboard to a client.  I want to make the dashboard so that it would update automatically and I have not been able to find a tutorial on Tibco's site or here for how to do this.

It would be great if someone could tell me how to make spotfire look in a particular place (server, desktop, wherever) for a new .csv file, open it and create a defined set of visualizations and then mail a pdf to the client.

I have been through the spotfire automation services manual but I can't find a specific guide to what I need it to do.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back and read thru the whole question again, including the other person's answer.  In order to be able to do what you want to do, you need to have Spotfire Server and Spotfire Automation Services.  Automation Services in a product that you have to purchase separately from Spotfire, although it is bundled with the Analyst client.

In your question you said -- It would be great if someone could tell me how to make spotfire look in a particular place (server, desktop, wherever) for a new .csv file, open it and create a defined set of visualizations and then mail a pdf to the client.

I made the assumption that you knew you needed Automation Services to do this.  All of my answers have been based around the use of Automation Services.  That's the only way to push an email to a user that I know of.  After you setup the Automation Services job, you also have to use Active Batch to schedule the Automation Services job, which I noted as part of the original 3 step process.

Comment: I really appreciate this.  We have automation services but I've not looked into active batch yet so I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make the dashboard so that it would update automatically and
>   I have not been able to find a tutorial on Tibco's site or here for
>   how to do this.

What you want to do is schedule updates to your linked data. What this will do is re-query the data-source at the specified schedule (once a day, twice an hour, etc) that you specify and cache it on the web server.

Here is the documentation for that.

- [Schedule Updates](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.1/doc/html/tsas_admin_help/GUID-77D00E34-7A16-4984-B4E0-A7F404A24B70.html)
- [Scheduling updates using Spotfire Server](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.1/doc/html/tsas_admin_help/GUID-8A271E80-C466-40F4-B206-70EF75CBB94F.html) (be sure to navigate down the sub items on the left)
- [Monitoring Schedule Updates](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.1/doc/html/tsas_admin_help/GUID-C907CB70-E906-4AA3-907C-7354977951F0.html)

> It would be great if someone could tell me how to make spotfire look
>   in a particular place (server, desktop, wherever) for a new .csv file,
>   open it and create a defined set of visualizations and then mail a pdf
>   to the client.

For this, you still want to use scheudle updates for the first part after you have linked your analysis to your csv file. Your file name will have to remain the same for spotfire to pick it up unless you customize this with some scripting. Once that is complete, you'll want to use Automation Services to complete your mailing a pdf.

- [Automation Services Tutorial](https://www.tibco.com/resources/tutorial-video/how-create-and-schedule-automation-services-job-spotfire)
- [Automation Services User Manual](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire-automation-services/7.6.0/doc/pdf/TIB_sfire_autsvcs_7.6.0_user_manual.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is a three step process.
1. In the desktop app, create a report (File -- Export -- to PDF -- prepared report.  In this step you are creating the export and telling Spotfire specifically what to export. [Where to find the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiyPD.png)
2. In the desktop app, create the Automation Services Job (Tools -- Automation Services Job Builder).  All jobs start with opening the file.  Then you create the export.  Then send the email. [Sample active batch jobe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sqXH.png)
3. Now, you have to automate the task.  This can be done with Windows Task Scheduler or Active Batch.

Those are the high-level steps.  There is a lot of syntax and detail in each of the steps, but this should get you started.  Please reply with more detailed questions on any one of the steps.

Comment: I think what I need happens before the first step. I have the file created and I can create scheduled task and have it email a report.  What I cannot figure out how to do is have the report include new data (in the form of a csv file) that comes in overnight before it is emailed.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: There is an automation services task for replacing the data source.  Add that task in before emailing.  The task order would be -- open the file, replace the data source, save the file, export and then email.  Then you get the new data.

Comment: If you could tell me where to specifically find that it would really helpful, JulieBMA.. Hopes deeply...

Comment: Tools menu -- Automation Services Job Builder.  Click Add button.  First, Add task -- "Open Analysis from Library".  Second, click Add button to add task -- "Replace Data Table" OR "Remap Data Sources".  If you have transformations or any insert columns, you'll need to use Remap.  If it's just a table, you can use Replace.  Third, click Add to add task -- Save Analysis to Library.  Fourth, click Add to add task -- Send Email.